# Is it there a log file for screensharing (vnc) with the incoming connections?

Tags: macos, vnc, screen-sharing

I found out that I had screensharing (vnc) turned on, Im using snow leopard, where can I see a log with all the incoming connections? or a log saying when it was enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If the connection was refused, there should be a server log under /Library/Logs.

AFAIK, OSX does not audit connections or login by default.